# How to compare two collections and get the number of matches between them? The collections also contains duplicates

Tags: java, .net

Collection 1:

```
{ "tom", "dick", "harry", "john", "smith", "dick" };
```

Collection 2:

```
{ "Rachel", "dick", "tom", "dick", "smith","harry","Orion"}
```

The duplicates should be counted twice.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: what to do with dup's? count them twice? once?

Comment: What type of collection it is, can you please specify..String, IEnumerable,JSON, etc. ?

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Comment: @Albin  *"What language do you want to use?"*  English?  I realize you were referring to Java/.Net, but this question hardly deserves code in answers and a textual description of the process would be much the same for either language.

Comment: It's either .net or java, but not both. A simple internet search on collection intersecting will answer this for you. Please do a little research before posting questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do a set intersection and get the size of the resulting set:

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"tom", "dick", "harry", "john", "smith", "dick"}));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Rachel", "dick", "tom", "dick", "smith", "harry", "Orion"}));

s1.retainAll(s2);  // s1 becomes the intersection of s1 & s2

System.out.println("Number of common elements: " + s1.size());
```

[EDIT] Should have read the question more carefully. Replace `Set` above with the [Bag](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html) implementation from Apache Commons and it will work for duplicates as well.

The `Set` implementation gives a size of 4 for s1 after the `retainAll` call, while the `Bag` version has a size of 5, which I believe is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use `Collections.frequency()` method to check the number of times the specific String object has occurred in the Collection.

**2.** Now you can **check frequency of each Object in the other Collection**, If the frequency count of any of the Object is zero in the another Collection, its obvious that this collection don't have that object, so these Collections are not equal.

**3.** If all the objects of the 1st collection are present in the 2nd then, try checking the objects of 2nd collection in the same way as i mentioned in point 2.